# How could one store custom info about a tag with taggit in Django?

Tags: python, django, tags, django-taggit

I'm making a system in which users can tag content where the number of times a certain tag has been assigned to a particular piece of content is significant and needs to be stored. I'm writing the system in Django and saw that taggit was the most popular of the pre-made tag system currently available (or at least, the most popular *maintained* system). How would one go about doing this? The [documentation](https://django-taggit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/custom_tagging.html) definitely has information about this, but I'm having some trouble with the vocabulary.

I'm very new to this, so any help would be very much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Never mind! I found a great resource to understand the "through model" . If you would like to take a look, here you go: [http://blog.hackedexistence.com/django-through-relationship-part-1-the-intermediary-model](http://blog.hackedexistence.com/django-through-relationship-part-1-the-intermediary-model)